# Parse CSV file in java, and delaing with empty values

Tags: java, arrays, csv, indexoutofboundsexception

I am parsing a CSV file into my program, spliting the values at the `,` element, and it's working fine, except for when I have lines that have missing values.

The parser is working like this:

```
import java.io.BufferedReader;
import java.io.FileReader;
import java.io.IOException;

public class CsvReader
{
    private static final String DELIMITER = ",";
    private final BufferedReader br;
    private final String path;

    public CsvReader(final String path) throws IOException
    {
        this.path = path;
        this.br = new BufferedReader(new FileReader(path));
    }

    public String[] nextLine() throws IOException
    {
        final String line = br.readLine();
        return (line == null) ? new String[0] : line.split(DELIMITER);
    }
}
```

The lines of data look like this (one line as an example):

```
J1024205,5028197000004,1,,00,20150603,,Accessories,Factory Test Article (m),ENG,010,110,5,T1,99,99,,,99,99,99,ZZ,ZZ,,5028197242053,30,35028197242054,6,,,OPZ848,3013607800239,OPZ848,,,,50,,
```

Most of the lines in the file complete with this: `50,85028197242127,8640`

But on some lines, the data is missing, so it ends like this: `50,,`

When the file is being processed, these lines are causing a `java.lang.ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException`.

How can I best deal with this, if I know that the numbers of objects in the file will remain constant?

I've been told that I need to replace empty values with a null value.

Comment: before doing split, use line.replace for '' to 'null'. since u need to replace the empty values with null.

Comment: @JishnuPrathap He means null value not "null" string :)

Answer (score 15, accepted):

From the Javadoc of `String.split(regex)`

> This method works as if by invoking the two-argument split method with the given expression and a limit argument of zero. **Trailing empty strings are therefore not included in the resulting array**.

So, in your case, when the string ends with `,,`, empty strings wont be part of the resultant array.

**To Fix:** Use this variant of split

```
line.split(DELIMITER, -1);
```

This will include all trailing empty strings. So you won't get an exception.

Comment: This is the best answer for this problem because an empty field should yield an empty String :)

Comment: @haywire No OP needs a null for empty values.

Comment: so, he uses the code of Codebender and replaces every "" by null. problem solved.

Comment: i have written it down in an answer in case it helps.

Comment: Saved me! Thank you

Answer (score 1):

This code results in array elements that are null if the column was empty.

```
// ... rest of OP's code

public String[] nextLine() throws IOException
{
    final String line = br.readLine();

    if(line == null)
    {
        return null; 
    }

    String columns[] = line.split(DELIMITER, -1);

    for(int i = 0; i < columns.length; i++)
    {
        if(columns[i].isEmpty())
        {
            columns[i] = null;
        }
    }

    return columns;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can this way also. Just call split method on the String returned with comma

```
public String replaceNullSplitLine(String line){
    if(line.endsWith(",")){
        line = line+"***";
    }
    line = line.replaceAll(",,", ",***,");
    return line;
}
```

Answer (score -1):

Check the length of the array before trying to use the last (and in that case non-existed) values

`myArray.length`