# Parsing csv file with indexOutOfBound in java

Tags: java, indexoutofboundsexception

I am new to Java and practice parsing csv file. I do understand what does `IndexOutOfBound` means, but I don't understand why my parsed data cannot do like all the tutorials I've visited such as https://examples.javacodegeeks.com/java-csv-parsing-example/

I can only read the first column, which is `data[0]`. There must be something wrong with my parsing method, but I cannot figure it out. Any help or hint is hight appreciated.

my data file looks like this:

```
  [0],    [1], [2],    [3]  ,    [4]    ,   [5]   ,  [6] ,   [7]  ,  [8] , [9]
class, gender, age, bodyType, profession, pregnant, isYou ,species, isPet, role
scenario:green,   ,         ,           ,         ,        ,      ,      ,
person, female, 24, average , doctor    , FALSE   ,        ,      ,      , passenger
animal, male  ,  4,         ,           , FALSE   ,        , dog  , TRUE , pedestrian
  .
  .
```

I tried to parse like this:

```
ArrayList<String> csvContents = new ArrayList<String>();    

try (BufferedReader csvReader = new BufferedReader(new FileReader(csvFile));) {
        String headerLine = csvReader.readLine(); //get rid of header

        while ((line = csvReader.readLine()) != null) { 
            csvContents.add(line);// add the line to the ArrayList      
        }

for (String csvLine : csvContents) {

            // split by comma and remove redundant spaces
            String[] data = csvLine.split("\\s*,\\s*"); 
            System.out.println(data[1]);// IndexOutOfBound

            Character character = null;
            String clazz = data[0].toLowerCase();// cannot use word "class" as a variable

            Profession professionEnum = Profession.valueOf(data[4].toUpperCase());  
            Gender genderEnum = Gender.valueOf(data[1].toUpperCase());
            BodyType bodyTypeEnum =BodyType.valueOf(data[3].toUpperCase());

            if (clazz.startsWith("scenario")) { 
                scenario = new Scenario();
                scenario.setLegalCrossing(clazz.endsWith("green"));
                continue;
            } else if ("person".equals(clazz)) {

                person = new Person(Integer.parseInt(data[2]), professionEnum ,genderEnum , bodyTypeEnum , Boolean.parseBoolean(data[5]));
                person.setAsYou(Boolean.parseBoolean(data[6]));
            } else if ("animal".equals(clazz)) {
                animal = new Animal(Integer.parseInt(data[2]) , genderEnum , bodyTypeEnum, data[7]);
                animal.setIsPet(Boolean.parseBoolean(data[8]));
            }
} catch (someException e) {
      e.printStackTrace();
}
```

**EDIT**

print out `csvLine` before split:

```
scenario:green,,,,,,,,,
person,female,24,average,doctor,false,false,,,passenger
person,male,40,overweight,unknown,false,false,,,passenger
person,female,2,average,,false,false,,,passenger
person,male,82,average,,false,false,,,pedestrian
person,female,32,average,ceo,true,false,,,pedestrian
person,male,7,athletic,,false,false,,,pedestrian
animal,male,4,,,false,false,dog,true,pedestrian
scenario:red,,,,,,,,,
```

Comment: you will be a lot better off using a proper csv reader, maybe http://opencsv.sourceforge.net/

Comment: Thanks, I've found this, but I am trying not to use the third party library. @ScaryWombat

Comment: Just do a simple split using comma `String[] data = csvLine.split(","); ` and then check the length of your array

Comment: I tried, the same result... That's why I asked the question...

Comment: Use a debugger. Check the line (or print it out) before you split it. I suspect you have an empty line at the start/end somewhere (or a line without ",").

Comment: Print out cvsLine before the split.

Comment: I printed it out and edited the post. Thank you all.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've figured it out. It's counterintuitive for me, though. I need to specify the `length` of the `data` array parsed to put every attribute like this:

```
ArrayList<String> csvContents = new ArrayList<String>();    

try (BufferedReader csvReader = new BufferedReader(new FileReader(csvFile));) {
    String headerLine = csvReader.readLine(); //get rid of header

    while ((line = csvReader.readLine()) != null) { 
        csvContents.add(line);// add the line to the ArrayList      
    }

for (String csvLine : csvContents) {

        // split by comma and remove redundant spaces
        String[] data = csvLine.split("\\s*,\\s*"); 
        System.out.println(data[1]);// IndexOutOfBound

        Character character = null;
        String clazz = data[0].toLowerCase();// cannot use word "class" as a variable


        if (clazz.startsWith("scenario"&& data.length == 1)) { 
            scenario = new Scenario();
            scenario.setLegalCrossing(clazz.endsWith("green"));
            continue;
        } else if ("person".equals(clazz)&& data.length == 10) {
            Profession professionEnum = Profession.valueOf(data[4].toUpperCase());  
            Gender genderEnum = Gender.valueOf(data[1].toUpperCase());
            BodyType bodyTypeEnum =BodyType.valueOf(data[3].toUpperCase());
            person = new Person(Integer.parseInt(data[2]), professionEnum ,genderEnum , bodyTypeEnum , Boolean.parseBoolean(data[5]));
            person.setAsYou(Boolean.parseBoolean(data[6]));
        } else if ("animal".equals(clazz)) {
            animal = new Animal(Integer.parseInt(data[2]) , genderEnum , bodyTypeEnum, data[7]);
            animal.setIsPet(Boolean.parseBoolean(data[8]));
        }
} catch (someException e) {
  e.printStackTrace();
}
```

Answer (score 1):

[image]

After spliting, the data just have one element, so that when you access data[1], then you get exception.
Solution: try with another regex like "," only.

Ps: your csv is malformed at

> scenario:green,   ,         ,           ,         ,        ,      ,      ,
>   Try to put one more ","

Comment: I can access the first column if I loop through the `data` array.

Answer (score 1):

you need to fill comlete data for all cells in a row.

For eg. first line in your csv, contains only 1 cell having value **scenario:green** which is data[0].

If you fill in data for all other cells in your csv, your will start receiving data[1], data[2], data[3]....

Comment: Is there a specific way to do this?

Comment: there are two ways to make sure that your **data** element has size 10 with all values.

**_First_** is to Make sure you fill all cells in csv. No cell should be blank.
. **_Second_** option is to use the split method as like this 
`String[] data = csvLine.split("\\s*,\\s*", -1); `

Comment: Thank you, sir. I've fixed the `IndexOutOfBoundException`, but I am facing another problem with `IllegalArgumentException` of no enum constant. I've referred to this post: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32068129/parse-csv-file-in-java-and-delaing-with-empty-values but it doesn't work for mine, still trying.

Comment: please refer this - https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6062925/enum-valueof-illegalargumentexception-no-enum-const-class

Comment: you are receiving this Exception because `Profession.valueOf(data[4].toUpperCase())` has input parameter as empty because data[4] is "" . You need to wrap such lines in try catch blocks.